# Silex 2.0 : the algorithm "bcrypt" is not supported

Tags: php, silex, bcrypt

I have a Silex project where i'm upgrading from Silex 1.3 to Silex 2.0.
The project works fine on 1.3 but i'm stuck with a bcryt encryption error since it seems default encoding changed with Silex 2.0.

Silex throw error `The algorithm "bcrypt" is not supported` with those 2 lines :

```
$pass_encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('bcrypt', true, 13);
$pass = $pass_encoder->encodePassword($si_pass, $si_salt);
```

I'm using XAMPP with PHP 5.5.28, mcrypt support is enabled and mcrypt_filter support is enabled.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: try to use `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder`

Comment: Add this at the top of your file `var_dump( hash_algos() );` and see if you have **bcrypt** in the array.

Comment: The use statement doesn't help. In the `hash_algos()` array there are many (md5, sha, ripemd, tiger, hava ...) but i can't find any bcrypt !

Comment: Wait, if i use this `$pass_encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder('bcrypt', true, 13);` it seems to work, it throw this error `Cost must be in the range of 4-31.`. I'm not familiar with this function, what are the parameters ?

Comment: `$pass_encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(13);`

Comment: Ok, problem solved, can you add an answer Max P. i'll accept it. And thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use bcrypt encoder

```
$pass_encoder = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder(13);
```